# Is it possible to get // to work locally?

Tags: macos, http, google-chrome, https, protocols

I do a lot of small-scale front-end projects so I don't want to spend to much time setting up dev enviroments. When I develop locally, I usually just write html and open the files in a browser. This usually works fine. At some times however I wish to use `//` instead of a protocol when referencing a file, like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is good cause it will work for both `http` and `https`, however if the protocol is `file://` it won't work. Is there some way to solve this? I would prefer to not having to run a local server and setting up domains for each project.